# How to plot columns on a chart when one column contains large values and the others small

Tags: excel, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008, data-visualization

I want to make a bar chart in SSRS and my table contains multiple columns. One column contains large values over 100 while the others contain values between 1 and 10. The other columns are pressed by the large columns. I multiplied the other columns values by 10 but I am not sure if this is the right way to make them visible. Please suggest.

Comment: If possible can you provide sample data and what have you tried and researched so far. Seems to me that you are trying to create a chart with 2 different scales or Y axis. This turorial should take you in the right direction: http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/charts/2_y_axes.php

Answer (score 1):

If you can get away with multiplying one value by a factor then it makes some sense to do this. Depending on what you are trying to achieve, I would consider having the larger values as columns and then the smaller values as a marker on the secondary axis. A step by step guide to do this is below, assuming you have the current column chart created.

1. Right-click on one of the columns of the smaller valued data set on the chart
2. Select **Change Series Chart Type..** and change it to a **line graph**
3. Click on the new created line
4. On the **Format tab**, under the **Current Selection** grouping, click **Format Selection**.
5. In the Format Data Series dialog box, on the **Series Options** tab, select **Secondary Axis**
6. Still within the Format Data Series dialog box, on the **Marker Options** tab, select a style of marker you would like to use, as well as the fill of the marker on the **Marker Fill** tab
7. Under the **Line Color** tab select **No line**
8. Click **Close** in the corner of the dialog box

This will create a chart similar to the below.

[image: Secondary axis chart example]

Comment: I think you are referring excel and I am using SSRS. Dont worry I will search it in SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, I think it's better to use scale break to make a better view.

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb934379(v=sql.100).aspx